# the ReadOnly property

Tags: vb.net

i have the class set like so:

```
private _eventId As String = ""
private _eventDate As Date = Nothing

Public ReadOnly Property eventId As String
    Get
        Return _eventId
    End Get
End Property
```

So the other one is the same way but the difference is that `eventId` works and `eventDate` does not. I have them in an object I want `eventDate readonly` along with others.

The error is "*Property `eventDate` is ReadOnly*"

Then the object is part of the main code is as follows

```
  Dim obj As New idObject(dr("EventID"))
  obj.eventDate = (dr("EventDate"))
```

so i dont understand why its not working what am i missing. if you want i will post all of the code but i figure if we can fix this one i can fix the rest im just out of options for now

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but why have the property read only if you're trying to modify it?

Comment: im not trying to mod it i need to declare it in order for it to show up but also i do have some things i need editable

Comment: Your example is a very good case for not making a property readonly. If you want to change it later from outside of the class having it read only doesn't make sense.

Comment: obj.eventDate = (dr("EventDate")) is modifying the property. (Note the =)

Comment: You say you want `eventDate` to be readonly - yet you say the 'error' is that `eventDate` is readonly. I don't at all understand your question.

Comment: You can't have it both ways, either it's `readonly` or it's not unfortunately.

Comment: @DNKROZ OHHhhh... you may have hit on what the question actually is...

Comment: you could pass the date in the constructor, so it can be set **once** and only when created

Comment: lol ok i need it to be read only only a few are able to be modified

Comment: @user3389158 Are you trying to test if `obj.eventDate` equals `(dr("EventDate"))`? If not, why are you trying to write to `obj.eventDate` at all?

Comment: Also as a note to the rest of the stuff here, having it be `readonly` and then only giving it a `get` accessor is a little redundant, isn't it?

Comment: im just learning this language i want items group can edit and cant

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if i've really understood what you're trying to achieve. But if you want to set the property from outside of the class you can't make it `ReadOnly` or you need to provide at least a constructor which allows to initialize it:

```
Public Sub New(eventID As Int32, eventDate As Date)
    Me._EventId = eventId
    Me._eventDate  = eventDate
End Sub
```

Now you can initialize the object via constructor:

```
Dim eventID As Int32 = dr.Field(Of Int32)("EventID")
Dim eventDate As Date = dr.Field(Of Date)("EventDate")
Dim obj As New idObject(eventID, eventDate)
```

On this way you have an object that must be initialized fully but which can't be changed easily afterwards.

Comment: An alternative is to provide a function that alters the property's backing field. But this is messy.

Comment: @Nick Technically that makes it modifiable which kind of defeats the purpose of the `readonly` attribute. You're making something `readonly` and then giving yourself a backwards way of modifying it. Kind of like going around your ass to get to your elbow. Small technicality.

Comment: I was replying to Nick's comment, not your answer; as your answer is the only way to have it allowed to be set from "outside the class" and still have it as `readonly`

Comment: @BenBlack precisely, which is why it's messy.